# AJAX Post without filename and query gives not allowed HTTP VERB

Tags: ajax, iis, asp-classic, prototype

We are working with an existing script that makes a `prototype` `AJAX` `POST` request to an URL like `/ds?params=`. When the call is made the result is:

> HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

If I use firebug and right click on the `AJAX` request and choose "Open in new tab" it does work, but `HTTP VERB`  is changed to `GET`

I tried adding a mapping to `asp.dll` in the configuration for the website in `IIS` as explained on [IIS forums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1201030.aspx), but it's still not working.

Comment: Is it `/ds?params=` or `/ds/?params=`?

Comment: `/ds?params=`, without the slash